# Is there any way to brick information back in old TortoSVN after it is updated?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have updated TortoiseSVN then all my information has gone. I need to bring it back . All my work was there. Can you please show me a way to bring it back ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: explain more in detail what is removed. I have no idea what your issue is

Comment: İ was  writing code with my collegeu in the same file.  I couldn't find old log.  I mean I could not find what things my friend or I  changed in code.

Comment: when you commit the changes you see your changes and if there were conflicts you would get a message. again, post more details what you did.

Comment: Voting to close as *unclear what you are asking* because the question does not have any context and there is no explanation of what "information has gone" means.